# R - How do I generate a histogram of this data frame?

Tags: r

I have an object `temp` whose data looks as follows:

```
   month mean(dep_delay)
   (int)           (dbl)
1      1       10.233333
2      2       10.687227
3      3       13.517602
4      4       14.554477
5      5       13.264800
6      6       20.350293
7      7       20.754559
8      8       12.619097
9      9        6.872436
10    10        5.880374
11    11        6.103183
12    12       17.368189
```

I generated this data using dplyr and the object holding this data is defind as follows:

```
class(temp)
[1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

I'm somewhat new to R and I'd like to generate a histogram of 'temp' so I can see the distribution of the data. However, the statement:

`hist(temp)` always generates the following error:

```
Error in hist.default(temp) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Comment: @ZheyuanLi - I already tried that. I get an error: Error in hist.default(temp[["mean(dep_delay)"]]) : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: Have you tried `hist(as.data.frame(temp)[,2])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually my first time to look at `dplyr`. I tried a small example, and it seems to work:

```
library(dplyr)
trees <- dbl_df(trees)

## A tibble: 31 x 3
#   Girth Height Volume
#   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1    8.3     70   10.3
#2    8.6     65   10.3
#3    8.8     63   10.2
#4   10.5     72   16.4
#5   10.7     81   18.8

hist(trees[[1]])
```

[image]

So I think if you just use `hist(temp[[2]])` you are fine.